# Make a form with 3 buttons

Tags: html, css, button

i want to make html form with 3 different action buttons. The buttons are : DAY;WEEK,MONTH.
When i click for example the DAY button i want to see DayImage in some folder, for example ImagesFolder, when click WEEK to see WekImage. I will put some images in that folder. Here is what i have so far

```
@using Portal.Framework.Models;

<form id="reportParametersForm" method="GET" action="@string.Format("{0}/{1}", @Url.Content("~/Reports/View"), ViewBag.Report)">
    <fieldset style="padding: 0.2em 0 1.2em 0;height:60px">
        <legend style="margin: 0 1px 0 10px;padding: 3px 36px 3px 20px;background-color: #494949;color: white;font-size: 11pt;">
        @Html.Resource(String.Format("Report_{0}", ViewBag.Report as string))</legend>

    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding = "0" style="font-size:x-small">        
        <tr valign="bottom" style="height:10px">
           <td width="20px" style="vertical-align: top">
            </td>
            <td width="30px" style="vertical-align: middle" align="center" nowrap="nowrap">
                <label style="font-size:small">
                    Time period</label>

                <button class="button" type="submit">
                    Day</button>

                <button class="button" type="submit">
                    Week</button>

                <button class="button" type="submit">
                    Month</button>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

But with this there is no action when i click some button. Also i want to have, later when i click the button to open some SSRS report. Plus how to add hover action to clicked button ?

Comment: It seems like a Latte template, which is unknown for me. But I think you should add `name` attribute to buttons to detect which one submitted the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have three different buttons with different actions by specifying with the formaction attr on the button like this

```css
form button:nth-child(2):hover{background-color:blue;}
form button:nth-child(3):hover{background-color:green;}
```

```html
<form action="blahblah.php" >
  <input type="text" name="blah" />
  <button formaction="send_to_num1.php">Number 1 php</button>
    <button formaction="send_to_num2.php">Number 2 php</button>
    <button formaction="send_to_num3.php">Number 3 php</button>
 </form>
```

have a look [HERE w3schools formaction](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formaction.asp)
for the hover part just add :hover psuedo in your css

Answer (score 1):

You can add formaction attribute to give different action for different buttons.

```
<button class="button" type="submit" formaction="action-url">Day</button>
```

But formaction attribute is not supported by older browsers. And for hover action to clicked button, use css.